# How can I get the root domain URI in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, url

Let's say I'm hosting a website at http://www.foobar.com.

Is there a way I can programmatically ascertain "http://www.foobar.com/" in my code behind (i.e. without having to hardcode it in my web config)?

Comment: Since that depends on the request, you might try looking in the `Request` object.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[HttpContext.Current.Request.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx) can get you all the info on the URL. And can break down the url into its fragments.

Comment: Yes, why the down vote? Don't see something marked as the answer -and- downvoted often. :/

Comment: I also do not like this answer. blesh has given the right one and this should have been marked as the answer...

Comment: -1 - Request.Url often gives a url such as "/folder1/folder2" and excludes the domain altogether.

Comment: @Justin: Request.Url gives you a Uri object which has all the pieces broken down for you. It shouldn't be giving you a string. At least not in the version of .net I am using

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding the code that makes it work like the answer below that has more votes up...

Comment: I downvoted because although it points to some possible implementation of the answer it is not an answer. Consider these cases: 1) When the root of the application is other than "/", 2) when the request URI includes the port, 3) differentiating between HTTPS and HTTP...

Comment: @IsaacLlopis: Opp didn't ask for root of application he asked for Root Domain, I don't understand why is the port an issue? Try Request.Url.Port. Hmm Also it gives you the Schema. In fact look at all the other answers they all use the same thing. I pointed the opp at how to find the info. So he could craft his own solution

Comment: George's answer should be marked as correct one - this one does not work in every case - e.g. port number in my case

Comment: @fubo HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port gives you the port And for Issac Yes I could have said HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host or HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority instead I pointed the Opp to the documentation for the Url class which gave him all the info he needed.

Comment: Potential host header injection.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url goes well inside controllers but in case you use it in a startup the Url looses important info. It returns http instead of https, 127.0.0.1 instead of custom origin and app name, port 80 instead of https specific (e.g. 443)

Comment: So all the answers here seem different from what worked for me. Is it the difference between asp.net and the core version? Request.Host.ToString() works for me.

Answer (score 186):

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

[Uri::GetLeftPart Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The GetLeftPart method returns a string containing the leftmost portion of the URI string, ending with the portion specified by part.

[UriPartial Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x82988a2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The scheme and authority segments of the URI.

Comment: Much better then parsing Url!

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Too many string manipulation that is unneeded.

Comment: Using this method, http:// www.lala.xxx/blah/blah will return http:// www.lala.xxx

Comment: +1 And not the same as .Authority which -- in the tests I made on localhost -- leaves off the protocol (http://) part.

Comment: UriPartial.Authority can cause problems with public domain url (it returns the internal url in some cases depending on the network configuration)

Answer (score 123):

For anyone still wondering, a more complete answer is available at http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/get-absolut-url-of-asp-net-application/.

```
public string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath
{
    get
    {
        //Return variable declaration
        var appPath = string.Empty;

        //Getting the current context of HTTP request
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        //Checking the current context content
        if (context != null)
        {
            //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
            appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                                    context.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                    context.Request.Url.Host,
                                    context.Request.Url.Port == 80
                                        ? string.Empty
                                        : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
                                    context.Request.ApplicationPath);
        }

        if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
            appPath += "/";

        return appPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  If the site is http://server:8080/MySiteName, it gets it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing actual code instead of a link somewhere else.

Comment: No problem. I've run into answers that include links to other sites and it's frustrating when the link is broken and then I have to search the Google cache or Wayback Machine for the content.

Comment: context.Request.Url.Port == 80 will cause problems within HTTPS

Comment: You're right. It should be checking for both 80 and 443, but I don't believe specifying port 443 and https as the scheme will hurt anything.

Comment: Attention! Not work for https. For https need to replace 
`context.Request.Url.Port == 80`
 by
`(context.Request.Url.Port == 80 && context.Request.Url.Scheme == "http") || (context.Request.Url.Port == 443 && context.Request.Url.Scheme == "https")`
or use answer below

Comment: Works also for localhost (if you are testing localy). If you don't need port, you can use "http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;

Answer (score 40):

If example Url is http://www.foobar.com/Page1

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url; //returns "http://www.foobar.com/Page1"


HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host; //returns "www.foobar.com"


HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme; //returns "http/https"


HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority); //returns "http://www.foobar.com"
```

Comment: Nope nope. `.Host` of `"http://www.foobar.com/Page1"` is `www.foobar.com`, not `foobar.com`.

Comment: yes you are right, updated the answer. @tchelidze thanks

Answer (score 30):

```
string hostUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host; //should be "http://hostnamehere.com"
```

Answer (score 16):

To get the entire request URL string:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

To get the www.foo.com portion of the request:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

Note that you are, to some degree, at the mercy of factors outside your ASP.NET application. If IIS is configured to accept multiple or any host header for your application, then any of those domains which resolved to your application via DNS may show up as the Request Url, depending on which one the user entered.

Comment: simplest solution here

Answer (score 6):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(host, "([^.]+\\.[^.]{1,3}(\\.[^.]{1,3})?)$");
string domain = match.Groups[1].Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : null;
```

host.com => return host.com
s.host.com => return host.com

host.co.uk => return host.co.uk
www.host.co.uk => return host.co.uk
s1.www.host.co.uk => return host.co.uk

Comment: I realise this is an old post, but nicely done NQuenault, I'm not great at Regex Expressions so well done.  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @nquenault any thoughts on how best to handle a host name like www.abc.com? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

--Adding the port can help when running IIS Express

```
Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string domainName = Request.Url.Host
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is older but the correct way to do this now is

```
string Domain = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
```

That will get the DNS or ip address with port for a server.

Answer (score 3):

This works also:

> string url = HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority;

Answer (score 1):

C# Example Below:

```
string scheme = "http://";
string rootUrl = default(string);
if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"].ToString().ToLower() == "on")
{
  scheme = "https://";
}
rootUrl = scheme + Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string host = Request.Url.Host;
Regex domainReg = new Regex("([^.]+\\.[^.]+)$");
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, "true");
if (domainReg.IsMatch(host))
{
  cookieDomain = domainReg.Match(host).Groups[1].Value;                                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return specifically what you are asking.

```
Dim mySiteUrl = Request.Url.Host.ToString()
```

I know this is an older question.  But I needed the same simple answer and this returns exactly what is asked (without the http://).

Comment: "without the http://" 
Then it's not "exactly what is asked"...