# Get fully qualified root URL of app without context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I would like to get the fully qualified root URI of an application without a context. I like the answer below, but if context is null then it will crash. Is there a better way to do this? Is there really nothing in the .NET API for this still (even 4.5)?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1671440/235334

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple bindings configured in IIS, how would it know, since there is no single fully qualified root URI?

I'm right now adding it to the web.config since I have an EMail generator that needs to know the URL, but technically I have at least three different valid URLs.

HttpContext does tell you how the current request is being called. You could use IIS Management APIs to [get Site Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.bindingcollection%28VS.90%29.aspx) though.

Answer (score 1):

You need something to ask for the url. Having a context suggests you're in the app & can ask it.

If you're not in the app then you need to get it so you can ask it. The IIS api might be able to help you there.