# MVC redirect changing domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am trying to redirect to a page in MVC website so I have the following code in my controller:

```
return Redirect("/test");
```

I am running my site locally through IIS on a domain of `test.local` and when I hit this controller I would expect to go off to `http://test.local/test` but instead, for some reason, it is redirecting me to `http://localhost/test`

Does anyone know how I can make it stay on the same domain without having to put the domain name into the redirect or do I have to include the domain name as well?

Please note as well that I am unable to use `RedirectToRoute` or `RedirectToAction` as the url is a separate application (under the same domain as the current site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a extension method that provides to redirect on the same domain. Maybe this helps

```
public static class ControllerExtension
{
    public static string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath
    {
        get
        {
            //Return variable declaration
            var appPath = string.Empty;

            //Getting the current context of HTTP request
            var context = HttpContext.Current;

            //Checking the current context content
            if (context != null)
            {
                //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
                appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                                        context.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                        context.Request.Url.Host,
                                        context.Request.Url.Port == 80
                                            ? string.Empty
                                            : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
                                        context.Request.ApplicationPath);
            }

            if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
                appPath += "/";

            return appPath;
        }
    }

    public static RedirectResult RedirectSameDomain(this Controller controller, string url)
    {
        return new RedirectResult(FullyQualifiedApplicationPath + url);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```
return this.RedirectSameDomain("/test");
```

#### Thanks to SO User Brian Hasden for `FullyQualifiedApplicationPath` and his answer on [How can I get the root domain URI in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214607/how-can-i-get-the-root-domain-uri-in-asp-net)