# How to get the Host Request.PathBase from Startup::Configure

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core

In my Startup class `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app...)` I'm setting up my cookie authentication in a pretty standard way:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
CookieName = cookieName,
//CookiePath = "",
AuthenticationScheme = cookieAuthSchemeName,
});
```

But I realized I was unable to set up the **CookiePath** the way I wanted because I don't know how to access the host server path base at this stage. For instance if my server is listening to http://internal.net:5000/**myappbase**/ then I could have a controller with one action and I would like to set up my cookie path to be **/myappbase/controller1** which I'm failing to do because at that stage, `Startup::Configure`, I can't get the information about the server listening to /myappbase. Maybe there is something injected that I could use, but I haven't found it yet.

What I've tried:

Injecting `IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor` didn't help.

I known I could be getting that easily anywhere else when I'm actually treating a request base on what I've read here: [How can I get the root domain URI in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214607/how-can-i-get-the-root-domain-uri-in-asp-net)

And I can also see that in the code of the CookieAuthenticationHandler, it is getting this information based on the Request:

```
protected string CurrentUri
{
    get
    {
        return Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host + Request.PathBase + Request.Path + Request.QueryString;
    }
}
```

Or

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    Domain = Options.CookieDomain,
    HttpOnly = Options.CookieHttpOnly,
    Path = Options.CookiePath ?? (OriginalPathBase.HasValue ? OriginalPathBase.ToString() : "/"),
};
```

but really, in the Startup::Configure, I don't know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the **ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)** method, add:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.OnAppendCookie = (e) =>
    {
        e.CookieOptions.Path = e.Context.Request.PathBase;
    };
    .....
});
```

Note: when a cookie is created and before it is sent to the client, the path of the cookie will be set to the Request.PathBase.

Comment: when a cookie is created and before it is sent to the client, the path of the cookie will be set to the Request.PathBase