# Get application virtual base path in aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I know that is located in `HttpContext.Request.PathBase`, however I need it to configure my cookie before I have any `HttpContext` (in `Startup.cs`).

My problem:

When devops configure application they have to set path twice. Once in IIS application (so hosting knows what should be served) and in my appsettings.json (so application knows where to set cookies - multiple instances can work on server). I would like to configure it once in IIS, and have config passed to my application.

Comment: Where (when) in Startup?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can be even after startup with IConfigureOptions. Configure or ConfigureServices are also ok.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205577/how-to-get-the-host-request-pathbase-from-startupconfigure/52463935#52463935

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the environment variable ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH. This is the variable AspNetCoreModule provides so that PathBase can be set correctly. See https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/blob/df88e322cc5e52db3dbce4060d5bc7db88edb8e4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration/WebHostBuilderIISExtensions.cs#L19

Comment: But what if you are using raw Kestrel?

Comment: Kestrel no longer directly supports base paths.

Comment: UsePathBase is still a thing, no?

Comment: This Environment Variable is only present if you are using  the `OutOfProcess` hosting model. If you are using `InProcess` the information is only present on the `HttpRequest.PathBase` property.

Answer (score 8):

There is a little confustion here that should be clarified.

You want to know application virtual path at application startup. However application virtual path is a concept of the hosting and specific request rather than underlying application. Hosting service uses this virtual path to map incoming url to application root. In IIS you can map multiple virtual paths to the same physical directory, e.g. /myApp1 and /myApp2 will point to the same application. Which of these paths do you want to get at application startup?

That's actually the reason why `IHostingEnvironment` interface does not provide any property for getting application virtual path. Another thing when application processes the request. In this case specific URL is requested and ASP.NET could provide requested virtual path in `HttpContext.Request.PathBase`.

You should reconsider your use case and check whether you actually need application virtual path for cookie configuration. It could be the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you still have doubts regarding cookie configuration, please formulate it as a new question with specific details for your scenario.

Comment: `/myApp1 and /myApp2 will point to the same application`
- no, it will be two separate copies of application with shared contentRoot, configs etc; each one should have correct PathBase.

Comment: Added problem description to question.

Comment: It is `IWebHostEnvironment` now.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when looking for the answer myself and none of the current answers work for me (the use of environment variable  ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH looked promising but that also failed.)

My solution ugly but works:

```cs
    public static string? GetIISVirtualPath(this WebApplication app)
    {
        object iServer = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
        PropertyInfo? pi = iServer.GetType().GetProperty("VirtualPath");
    
        return (pi?.GetValue(iServer) as string)?.ToLower();
    }
```

Rummaging about in the source the IServer implementation under IIS has an "VirtualPath" path property.  So I grab that on startup.

Evil because MS can change this if they so desire, breaking this solution but I'll take that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Another extension similar to that @AnthonyWJones suggested:

```cs
    public static string? GetIISVirtualPath(this WebApplication app)
    {
        IServer iServer = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
        return iServer.GetIISVirtualPath();
    }
    
    public static string? GetIISVirtualPath(this IServer server)
    {
        PropertyInfo? pi = server.GetType().GetProperty("VirtualPath");
        return (pi?.GetValue(server) as string)?.ToLower();
    }
```

The second one could also be handy with Dependency Injection.

Answer (score -2):

Just to add you can use `@Url.Content("")` in Javascript to get virtual directory base path.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/app/myapp.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```